# How can I install just security updates from the command line?

Tags: command-line, package-management, updates, security

`sudo apt-get upgrade` installs all updates, not just security updates. I know that I can use Update Manager to select only important security updates, but is there a way to do this from the command line?

Comment: I assume you meant to refer to apt-get (dist-)upgrade?

Comment: I don't think so. dist-upgrade takes the entire system to a new release. I'm talking about day-to-day updates, like the ones you see in Update Manager.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now. Heh, I run apt-get update so often, I type it without thinking. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: You want "apt-get dist-upgrade", not "apt-get upgrade". "dist-upgrade" isn't for new releases (that's "do-release-upgrade" a separate command). Using "dist-upgrade" means it will handle changing dependencies of the new packages. This can be important.

Comment: I don't think @KeesCook is correct. According to apt docs you want to use apt-get upgrade unless you are moving between distributions. Only under rare conditions should a dist-upgrade be necessary v. and upgrade when running a released (e.g. not currently beta/rc) ubuntu.

Comment: dist-upgrade is the normal operation performed by the Update Manager GUI. For packages such as the kernel where there is a `linux-image-generic` package, depending on the current image, eg `linux-image-3.x.y-zz-generic` (each version of which is a separate package name), dist-upgrade (which allows new packages to be installed to satisfy dependencies) will perform this upgrade, whereas upgrade will show the kernel package as held-back.

Comment: Surprising that there are no good `apt-get` based answers for this, considering how prominently it is listed on each server

Comment: Actually ILIV answer below is really good. First you can list the packages that are to be updated, then you can run `sudo apt-get install <name>` of only the packages to be upgraded. That allows you to only upgrade packages that represent a security issue.

Comment: Two [duplicate](http://serverfault.com/q/270260/85654) [threads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35825436/712526) (with different solutions & different explanations).

Answer (score 373, accepted):

The package [unattended-upgrades](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unattended-upgrades) provides functionality to install security updates automatically.

You could use this, but instead of configuring the automatic part you could call it manually:

```sh
sudo unattended-upgrade -d --dry-run
sudo unattended-upgrade -d # Idem --debug
```

If you want to run it quietly instead:

```
sudo unattended-upgrade
```

**Note**: When you call unattended-upgrade you leave the "s" off the end (on newer versions there is a symlink to avoid this).

This assumes that the package is installed by default, which it probably is. If not, just do:

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

See also [`/usr/share/doc/unattended-upgrades/README.md`](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: For disabling the automatic execution of `unattended-upgrade` you are probably needing to modify `/etc/cron.daily/apt`, but not sure it is "correct" to do so

Comment: side note: for Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS server, `unattended-upgrades` is not installed by default.

Comment: Since you're doing this from the command line, use `-v` for info messages or `-d` for debug messages. Otherwise the utility will be very silent, in which case you would need to check the logs in `/var/log/unattended-upgrades`. You can also use `--dry-run` to simulate but not actually upgrade anything. For more info and other options, use `--help` to get the help message.

Comment: i learned a few things about `unattended-upgrades` today. thanks!

Comment: "for monitoring how it goes", it is just debug non-interactive messages right?

Comment: For me, the README was gzipped, so to read it, I used `gzip -dc /usr/share/doc/unattended-upgrades/README.md.gz | less`.

Comment: @Gogowitsch: you'll be happy to know there's a purpose-built tool for this: `zless /usr/share/doc/unattended-upgrades/README.md.gz` (https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/05/zcat-zless-zgrep-zdiff-zcmp-zmore-gzip-file-operations-on-the-compressed-files/)

Comment: I tried the command, it seems it's updating everything. For example, it's updating vim right now. How is vim related to security package?

Comment: @sgon00 Vim recently had a security bug in it:  https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6195-1

Answer (score 144):

### A Few Tips On How To Manage Updates

This applies both to Debian and Ubuntu, but more specific instructions for Ubuntu follow.

- Show security updates only :

  ```
  apt-get -s dist-upgrade |grep "^Inst" |grep -i securi
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d
  ```

  or

  ```
  /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p
  ```
- Show all upgradeable packages

  ```
  apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep "^Inst"
  ```
- Install security updates only

  ```
  apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep "^Inst" | 
      grep -i securi | awk -F " " {'print $2'} | 
      xargs apt-get install
  ```

**Notes:**

- Sometimes Ubuntu shows security updates as if they're coming from $release-updates repository. This is so, I'm told, because Ubuntu developers push security updates to $release-updates repository as well to expedite their availability.

  If that's the case, you can do the following to show security updates only:

  ```
  sudo sh -c 'grep ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list | 
      grep security > /etc/apt/sources.security.only.list'
  ```

  and

  ```
  apt-get -s dist-upgrade -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/sources.security.only.list -o Dir::Etc::SourceParts=/dev/null  | 
      grep "^Inst" | awk -F " " {'print $2'}
  ```
- Check what services need to be restarted after package upgrades. Figure out what packages you are going to upgrade beforehand and schedule your restarts/reboots. The problem here is that unless you restart a service it still may be using an older version of a library (most common reason) that's been loaded into memory before you installed new package which fixes a security vulnerability or whatever.

  ```
  checkrestart -v
  ```

  However, keep in mind that `checkrestart` may list processes that shouldn't necessarily be restarted. For example, PostgreSQL service may be keeping in its memory reference to an already deleted xlog file, which isn't a valid reason to restart the service.

  Therefore, another, more reliable, way to check this using standard utils is the following little bash script that I shamelessly stole from https://locallost.net/?p=233

  It checks if running processes on a system are still using deleted libraries by virtue of keeping copies of those in active memory.

  ```
  ps xh -o pid |
  while read PROCID; do
         grep 'so.* (deleted)$' /proc/$PROCID/maps 2> /dev/null
         if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                 CMDLINE=$(sed -e 's/\x00/ /g' < /proc/$PROCID/cmdline)
                 echo -e "\tPID $PROCID $CMDLINE\n"
         fi
  done
  ```

Comment: I notice only now this post. It is extremely precise. Thanks a lot (+1)

Comment: where does 'checkrestart' come from? I can't find it in Ubuntu Trusty. I did find "needrestart" which looks like it would fit in your instructions?

Comment: It can be found in debian-goodies package: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/debian-goodies. There's also needrestart. You can find both on Xenial by running: $apt-cache search checkrestart

Comment: I get "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)" even with sudo. Is this something specific to one of the updates or the commands you've provided?

Comment: Most likely it's about an incorrect/abnormal termination of dpkg that left a lock file uncleared. Doesn't happen normally until, e.g. installation of a package doesn't finish successfully (full disk, etc.) You probably cannot run other apt-get and dpkg commands, can you?

Comment: Your grep for `grep -i securi `, never seems to work. Packages don't seem to be labeled that way.

Comment: $ apt-get -s dist-upgrade |grep "^Inst" |grep -i securi 
Inst liboxideqt-qmlplugin [1.17.9-0ubuntu0.16.04.1] (1.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates, Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-security [i386]) []
... in other words - it works.

Comment: for me if I don't include -y  on apt-get install it quits on the first yes/no question fyi

Comment: I believe the `apt-get | grep | xargs apt-get` will change the packages your system thinks you *must* have installed. While `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade everything, it won't list some random dependency as a "required" package by doing so, whereas running `apt-get install <pkg>` does do that.

Comment: Very helpful! 

The double grep can be replaced like this: `grep "^Inst.*securi.*" `
That is, it starts with Inst and contains securi(ty).

Comment: *Install security updates only* fails with an error in zsh or bash unless I add the non-interactive flag:  `xargs apt install -y`

Answer (score 48):

replace `/etc/apt/preferences` with the following:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=lucid-security
Pin-Priority: 500

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 50
```

now a simple `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade all security updates only.

Why (and how) this works: The preferences file will pin all packages from Ubuntu distribution to priority 50, which will make them less desirable than already installed packages. Files originating from security repository are given the default (500) priority so they are considered for installation. This means that only packages that are considered more desirable than currently installed ones are security updates. More information about pinning in the [apt_preferences manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html).

You can temporarily promote a certain distribution for updates with the `--target-release` option that works with `apt-get` and `aptitude` (at least) which will allow you pin certain releases so that they are eligible for upgrade.

If you wish to use this for scripts only and not make it default for the system, you can place the rules in to some other location and use this instead:

```
apt-get -o Dir::Etc::Preferences=/path/to/preferences_file upgrade
```

This will make apt look for the preferences file from a non-default location.

The preferences file given as an example doesn't apply to third party repositories, if you wish to pin those too you can use `apt-cache policy` to easily determine the required keys for pinning.

Comment: Thanks for taking time for a thorough answer. I _think_ I understand how it works. But when I create the /etc/apt/preferences file and run apt-get upgrade, it wants to upgrade all packages, not just security updates. The list upgrade before and after are exactly the same, _except_ with /etc/apt/preferences it doesn't want to upgrade Leafpad, which I built from source and installed "by hand" with dpkg. It's very strange to me, but may mean something to you.

Comment: You can see what is going on with apt-cache policy command. Pick one of the packages that isn't getting a security fix and run `apt-cache policy packagename`. This will list the priorities for various versions. You should see various lines and different priorities. If there are no lines with the priority 50, the pinning isn't affecting the packages in question for some reason.

Comment: I had followed this answer in the past. Today I found out that due to this answer, 68 security update packages were NOT installed on my server and didn't show up as potential install candidates. This is NOT A GOOD ANSWER!

Answer (score 14):

The following is confirmed in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Use the `unattended-upgrade` package.

Look at the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. There should be a section at the top that is:

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

Note how it has been configured to only allow unattended upgrades for security packages, by default.

Modify the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` similar to:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

This will run automatic unattended security upgrades, once per day.

Now, to run manually: `sudo unattended-upgrade`.

To test as a dry-run, without doing anything: `sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run`.

Sources: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates

Comment: Is there a way to make this a monthly schedule?

Comment: @mike.b93, I believe setting `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "30";` Would do this--every 30 days.

Answer (score 12):

If you wish to install only security updates the following will work. First it lists all upgradeable packages, filter out only the ones coming from a security repo, cut the returned strings at the first field, and then passes them to apt-get install for package update.

```
sudo apt list --upgradable | grep security |cut -d\/ -f1|xargs sudo apt-get install -y
```

Comment: @keypress has a great improvement for this elegant solution: using `--only-upgrade` to make sure no new packages will be installed. I just tested it with `apt` and it works.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `sudo apt update` needs to be run beforehand, to make sure `sudo apt list` finds everything new.

Comment: Yes that's correct; apt-get update should have already been ran before being able to list any security updates.

Comment: Note that if any of the installs require interactive input (e.g. to decide if existing user-edited config files should be overwritten with new ones), then this one-liner may stop half-way through with an error (it did in my case). Might be best to omit the `|xargs sudo ...` part and just list out the packages so you can install them one-by-one (assuming there aren't tooo many)

Comment: working for me, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

On Debians I use this command to do only security updates:

```
apt-get install -y --only-upgrade $( apt-get --just-print upgrade | awk 'tolower($4) ~ /.*security.*/ || tolower($5) ~ /.*security.*/ {print $2}' | sort | uniq )
```

Comment: This (accidentally?) does not include the various linux-{modules,images,headers}-* packages. Which is prefect for my purpose, where a pretty much unattended system has an out of tree kernel module that's tedious to compile after each kernel update.

Comment: Yes, this is accidentally - I thought that security updates of `linux-*` packages also come from security repositories. But I have not checked it.

Comment: Yeah, the Long Term Support HardWare Enablement stack updates come from the *-updates repos. So there the text 'security' is not in there.

Answer (score 4):

Although its pretty ugly, you could disable all the repositories apart from the security repository and then do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I haven't tested it, but in theory it would only find updates in the security repo and apply them...

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility. I'll look into it. I'm no good at BASH, but I may try to make a script to do it.

Comment: OK, I disabled all but the Ubuntu security repos and ran a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` (cancelling before any upgrades were done). Then I re-enabled all my repos, ran `sudo apt-get updatee`, and opened Update Manager. The packages marked as security updates were not exactly what `apt-get upgrade` found, but they were very close -- close enough for me. I still wish I knew exactly how Update Manager does it and how to do the same from the command-line, but this will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- `apt-get update`: 
  just read the entries in repository - acording to existing list. Needed to check what is new.
- `apt-get upgrade`: all updates for installed packages without kernel modules. No release update.
- `apt-get dist-upgrade`: all updates for installed packages also with kernel modules. No release update.
- `apt-get` with parameter `-s`: test only, no changes performed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that achieves this in a few different ways:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# List upgradable packages
apt-get update
apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null
# List security upgrades
test "$(apt-get upgrade -s -y)" && (apt-get upgrade -s -y)
# List upgradable apt packages then upgrade
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y  -V | grep '=>' | awk '{print$1}' && test "$(apt-get upgrade -y)"
```

Comment: An explanation of how this is supposed to achieve the goal would be nice. Because it doesn't actually work -- it does nothing to select security upgrades only, it just does all upgrades, security or not.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an option in either apt-get or aptitude, however someone had the [same question](https://superuser.com/questions/130087/how-to-install-just-security-updates-via-the-command-line-on-ubuntu) on SuperUser. The only response is:

```
Check and adjust /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrade. 
Did you replace 'karmic' with the code name of your Ubuntu?
```

No reply as to whether that worked however.

Comment: It appears that the method described in that wiki page depends on setting aptitude's --target-release argument to <release>-security. Like the OP of that question, that method installs all upgrades, not just security upgrades.

Reading the apt-get and aptitude man pages, I don't think the --target-release argument is even intended to limit upgrades to just security, though I'm not sure just what it _is_ for.