# How do I check only security updates from the command-line?

Tags: apt, updates, package-management

Is there a way to **quickly check for the availability of security updates** from the command line?

On my 12.04 system running `apt-get update` fetches **20MB of data** about available packages every time I run it, hitting many repositories along the way. Then I can use any of the methods described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194/how-can-i-install-just-security-updates-from-the-command-line/272#272) to actually perform the update.

My question is just about **detecting the availability of security updates** (ie, not performing the actual upgrade using apt-get/aptitude/etc): is there a quick check that can be done from the command line that provides a yes-no answer the question "are there security updates available?". I would like to run that before running the lengthy `apt-get update` + actual upgrade.

I suppose I don't need to download 20MB of data to know the answer to that every day.

Comment: Check this:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/65245/apt-get-update-only-for-a-specific-repository
http://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository

Comment: You mean the `apt-get update` fetches 20MB of package metadata?

Comment: @JeremyKerr: yes, it does if you are on the main (archive/us.archive) server because the package lists are updated every half-hour...there's one or two long threads about it on AU from international/low-speed users who are very disappointed about it.

Comment: @izx: interesting, just ran a test using `apt-get update` using an Australian mirror (I'm in .au); total downloaded was 1.3MB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *My question is just about detecting the availability of security updates*

Yes, that's doable with the caveat that the normal `apt-get update` will do a full refresh when you next run it (20 MB means it's doing that anyway).

- `sudo sh -c 'grep precise-security /etc/apt/sources.list > /etc/apt/secsrc.list`
- And if you then run the following, you'll see if there are any security updates available ([sample output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1046971/)):

  ```
  sudo sh -c 'apt-get -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="secsrc.list" \
  -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" update && \
  apt-get --assume-no upgrade'
  ```
- This tells `apt-get` to temporarily use the special security-only sources list, and then runs `upgrade`, automatically answering no.
- If there are any, run proper `apt-get update` (which will do a full refresh), and then upgrade.
- You could make the above a bash script with a simple grep/exit code check at the end if you don't feel like parsing the apt-get output :)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, many thanks!:) one quick question: my /etc/apt/secsrc.list file makes no reference to the 'partners' repository (just to 'main restricted', 'universe' and 'multiverse'), will I still get notified of security updates for the packages in that repository?

Comment: @laramichaels, the *partners* repository contains [just fifteen packages](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1051858/), and these are basically proprietary binaries wrapped in a .deb. Incremental "security" updates are not released for these, and I imagine even regular updates are infrequent (think Adobe Reader). I'd just add the actual repository (`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner`) to `secsrc.list` given the [tiny size (5 kb)](http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/binary-i386/) of the partner update file.

Comment: @laramichaels, I also added a more detailed answer to [your previous question](http://askubuntu.com/a/153903/58612) about the partner security updates aspect. The accepted answer was erroneous IMO, so please have a look when you have a free moment and accept mine instead if you think it's better.

Comment: What is this bit for? `-o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-"`

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper I guess (after searching online) because there is a bug reported online, with title `Bug#449386: To use a separate sources.list, OPTIONS needs to set Dir::Etc::SourceParts along with Dir::Etc::SourceList`.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what the question is asking, but if you've already run `apt update`, you can see what security updates are available using:

```
sudo apt list --upgradable | grep -e "-security"
```

which will give you something like:

```
libssl1.0.0/xenial-updates,xenial-security 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.9 i386 [upgradable from: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8]
openssl/xenial-updates,xenial-security 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.9 i386 [upgradable from: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8]
```