# what is the best way to upgrade security patches on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: updates, security

I am trying to upgrade security patches on production boxes.
Need to know how can i plan this activity.
I also need to make sure that in case something is wrong then how do i roll the updates.

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing / wanting . If you are writing your own patches , or you are downloading patches from somewhere and using something other then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` support will be likely  limited.

Comment: Well i am using official ubuntu repo.I am looking for an option to install specific security update and Just in case anything goes wrong with any specific update ,I am looking for option to have a rollback to previous state.

Comment: Then you simply keep your system up to date and updates, including security patches, will be installed when they are available. You may also automate security only updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/194/how-can-i-install-just-security-updates-from-the-command-line

Comment: I want to do it manually.Is there any option to do that.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/152179/how-do-i-check-only-security-updates-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

You do that by using common business practices:

1. Read the [Ubuntu Security notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/)
2. Keep [system back-ups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) of your system (you're definitely user type 4)
3. Have a test system (virtual or not) to test updates before rolling them out
4. Use secure passwords and don't re-use them.
5. [Install software intelligently](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) and keep it updated as well.
6. etc...

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask