# Email notification about automatic installed security updates

Tags: command-line, server, 16.04, updates, notification

Is there a way to get an Email-notifications when Ubuntu make an automatic security update?

It should contain something like: the name of the update and what is updated. for example: so i can check if tomcat, PhP or self written programms etc are still working with my serversoftware and websites after the update. if there where many updates it should be send daily.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292255/how-to-make-my-server-email-me-when-there-are-security-updates?rq=1