# How can I install a security updates before a given date?

Tags: automation

[How can I install just security updates from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194/how-can-i-install-just-security-updates-from-the-command-line)

The above question does a good job of describing how to do security updates only.

Is there a way to install all security updates that were released before certain date?

The context here is a Chef recipe. I'd like to install all updates as of today on QA systems. Then when I release this to production it should just install security updates up to that date.

I could maintain a list, but as you can imagine it could be hard and some systems might be in various states.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an automated way to do this, at least not elegant way to, but you have two options:

1. Make your own cache/repository and make clients take their updates from this. This is the most definitive solution since you totally control what updates your clients gets.
2. Deactivate automatic upgrades and parse the change logs to get dates of releases, then install that specific version using APT. This is more complicated and error prone.

Security upgrades normally doesn't change the way that software behave and the question you linked should do the job if you want to get a fully protected system.