# Limited download for updates

Tags: synaptic

As we travel quite a lot, often we are limited to Caravan site networks with only 50Mb downloads permitted. Currently I'm being told I need 66.7Mb of updates. Is there a way using Synaptic I can select what is strictly necessary? Please be aware I would not have any idea what to select, and so can I let Ubuntu 14.04, decide?

Thank you for both answers to date, I'll try both suggested options. I cannot decide which gave the better answer and I cannot tick both. Hall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to update just one application because of an issue, using the install keyword will do it.

sudo apt-get install firefox

As it's already installed, it will just updated to latest (not install twice or anything silly)

Note that if you get 2/3rds way through an update download and run out of network, apt will cache the downloads, and resume once you get more data.

Run of the mill upgrades wouldn't be worth wasting your 50Mb on. Save that for useful stuff like email & web content.

Comment: David, do I understand you correctly? If I downloads "bits" over say three days,  (updates are now 166Mb) there will be no problems with "broken data" (I can't think of another term) and I can update as usual?

Comment: Correct, apt is very tollerant of interupted downloads.  How have you fared in your travels?

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with your OS, I don't think that you can't wait with updates until you have normal Internet connection.

But reading this answer:
[How can I install just security updates from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194/how-can-i-install-just-security-updates-from-the-command-line)

you can do this by going into a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and entering:

```
sudo unattended-upgrade
```

and if it is not installed, then first install it, by

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrade
```