# How to enable automatic security updates on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, security

I have a laravel app on a ubuntu 20.04 server. How do I enable it to automatically apply only security updates?

does the following only install security updates or other updates:

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

my sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades is as follows:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
    // Extended Security Maintenance; doesn't necessarily exist for
    // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
    // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
    // should also install from here by default.
    "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
    "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
   //"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
   //"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
   //"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/194/how-can-i-install-just-security-updates-from-the-command-line is still valid.

Comment: @Rinzwind that for calling it from command line.  The post doesn't give any example to enable it for automatic security updates?

Comment: Your config looks like everything is commented out except security updates. For debug purposes you can actually manually run the unattended-upgrades:   `sudo unattended-upgrade -d`

Comment: See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260567/how-can-i-keep-ubuntu-updated-automatically/1260789#1260789), if you want more details.

Comment: @Nmath what about this line: `"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";` which isnt commented? what is that line doing?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Go to Software and Updates and enable Livepatch.
Canonical Livepatch helps keep your system secure by applying security updates that don't require a restart.

Or you can use the terminal for security updates using the command:

`sudo unattended-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is the following:
The reconfigure brings up a text ui to confirm and then you are done.

sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades